# How to add files from different input controls into gridview

Tags: asp.net

Below is my requirement. I will have two browse buttons on the page , and two upload buttons on the page.

My requirement is to have both the attachments uploaded by the user to be displayed in a gridview in one row.

Upload1 and Upload2 are the two attachments uploaded by the user and i need to get them as below in the gridview.

```
Attachment 1  Attachment 2    Delete   
Upload1       Upload2         Delete
```

Can you please help me with an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: What are 'browser buttons'?  File browsing?  Also, this seems like a poor scenario for using a GridView.  Why did you choose it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should be able to do this by using a TemplateField when you define your columns:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstColumn">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fu_FirstFile" runat="server" /><br/>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_UPloadFirst" runat="server" /> 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SecondCOlumn">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fu_SecondFile" runat="server" /><br/>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_UPloadSecond" runat="server" /> 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```